# Convert 3d array of image to 1d

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I converted my image of size (256,256,3) to blocks of 8X8 pixels and each of this block has an array of (8,8,3). I was just wondering how can I flatten each of the block to an array(vectors) of size 64.

```
img_one = cv.imread("001.jpg")
blocks = np.array([img_one[i:i+8, j:j+8] for j in range(0,256,8) for i in range(0,256,8)])
blocks[0].ravel()
```

I tried using the ravel function for the first block of image but it converts it to array of size 192 instead.

Comment: 8x8 is 64, but you have 3 channels, so 64x3 is 192. So you cannot make it just 1D of 64 unless you throw out channels or average the channels.

Comment: ok i think that cleared it up conceptually thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "sliding blocks"? Please define your term. What are you ultimately trying to do? Perhaps you want 1D of 64 with 3 channels so (64,3)

Comment: yes 1d of 64 with 3 channels

Comment: try block[x].reshape(64,3)

Comment: have you considered that the data is **color** and you should **convert to gray**? use cvtColor

Comment: ok that makes more sense thanks